# How do I get msbuild to recognize characters from another alphabet?

Tags: msbuild

Some quick background. I need to compile a .net program written by a coworker in Spain. His code contains characters that my version of msbuild tags as invalid (such as the ñ), but msbuild on his computer compiles the project just fine.

Lastly, he is on windows and I am on a mac, but I may need to run the compilation on a windows machine in the future. Both my mac and my potential windows machines are US versions.

How can I get msbuild to recognize the characters as valid ones?

Comment: Can you share with us the error you're getting?

Comment: It's almost 400 of the same error saying that a character is invalid and providing a filename, row, and column. Going to those rows and columns in the specified files, you see the special character there.

Comment: The invalid char is in a `.cs` file? Please, bring as much information as you can share.

Comment: It's a .vb file. He wrote the program using visual basic. I have to be able to compile this on the command line to use with a CI/CD tool.